# Preview Image of Custom View in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, image, view, preview

Is it possible to set an image, for a custom "View" or "Control" to be shown in Eclipse? So that it somehow loads the image of the View so it can be previewed before adding it? Say for an open Library of Views, this would be ideal and good. I have no clue where to start looking.

To clarify, when going under "Form Widgets" there are preview of the controls like Buttons, TextView, RatingBar for example. Only this functionality for a control. I'm not sure if it's Eclipse specific, but...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `ImageView` try below code in xml file:

```
<ImageView 
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Comment: Like the answer above and this, it seems like the question got misunderstood or I'm totally missing something. I want to render the way my View do look or might look like and be able to show a "rendered" image or an "icon" under "Custom & Library Views" for easier navigation and in a open Library would look more "professional", so to speak. All this does is add an image to my View.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible.

Here my CustomView (which extends `ImageView`)

[image]

Comment: This is showing the default icon that all empty custom views do.I asked by either rendering a "preview", preferably the control or how to set some image for it. Would be good when the list of Custom Views get long, easier to navigate by seeing the controls.